# How to make CardView noticeable over images?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am uploading two screenshots for the comparison.

**CardView noticeable**
[image]

**CardView unnoticealbe** (when scroll down)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add top margin of your RecyclerView view, so when you scroll the RecyclerView items your Top card views will be noticeable as your first screen.
somthing like

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
```

Comment: Yes. But it is unnoticeable when scrolling down to images.

Comment: In my case problem solved by -
1. Add marginTop or padding top of your RecyclerView. 

2. add cardElevation to your top "search product" cardView as you do with your RecyclerView item. 

3. Adding following code in your "search product" cardView 
            app:contentPadding="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear to me. Anyways after looking at those two images you can..

Try giving margin_top to your grid recycler view.

```
android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
```

And you need to give cardElevation property to your cardView.

```
app:cardElevation="8dp"
```

Comment: Yes. But it is unnoticeable when scrolling down to images

Answer (score 0):

You can use card_view:cardCornerRadius="" for the rounded corners and card_view:cardElevation="" for the shadow effect in your XML layout.

Below code you can check

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope this will help you.